# Returning value from range for any of the values that are looked up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data set:
[image] 
and use the index/match function to check if the value in column A has a corresponding value in column b compared to values that are in another sheet called Data:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH('Data A1'!,A:A,0)),"")
```

The goal of this exercise is to identify there is value in column B for **any value** in column A and here is where my formula fails, because for value 2 the formula returns an empty cell, because it is only checking for the first value in the list and not all values. 
Any ideas on how I can fix the formula to reflect ABC when the value 2 is in the list? I am hoping for an outcome like this:

[image]
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to return all the instances or just the first?  For example in your test data above there would be two, rows 4 and 5.  Or, do you only care if it exists in the dataset?

Comment: I ultimately only care if a value exists in column B.

Comment: Then a simple COUNTIFS() will do that.  `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,2,B:B,"abc"),"Here","Not Here")`

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated it differently. I only care if a value exists in column B for the value 2 in row 2 and 8 but I still want to return the correct values for values 2 in rows 4+5.

Comment: maybe show in another picture you desired outcome.

Comment: Just added the desired outcome. So it basically counts the rows that the value from column A matches but are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to use a blank column to do this.  In a blank column put the following formula in the first row:

```
=IF(B1="",SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))="")*($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))=A1)),B1)
```

Then Copy down the range.

[image]